# How to use the Owl nav buttons and Owl dots for this coding

Tags: jquery, html, css

Owl navigation buttons and Owl dots are not working. How to make them work?

Below is my source code:

```html
<div id="three" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
        <div class="owl-stage">
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-nav">
        <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
        <div class="owl-next">next</div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-dots">
        <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
        <div class="owl-dot">span>/span></div>
        <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please detail more about your question.

Comment: when i click on the Owl nav and Owl dots, they are not working.

Comment: can you please create an example in jsfiddle or code snippet ?